# How to display the original line number in awk after removing common lines

Tags: awk

I have the following code that only displays the lines that are not in the first file:

```
'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' compareAgainst myFile
```

How can I include the original line number next to the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a){print FNR,$0}' compareAgainst myFile
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
NR==FNR{                     ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file compareAgainst is being read.
  a[$0]                      ##Creating array a with index $0 here.
  next                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
!($0 in a){                  ##Checking condition if current Line is not present in array a then do following.
  print FNR,$0               ##Printing line number and current line here.
}
' compareAgainst myFile      ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Is that all it needed? xD Thanks! That was fast. I will accept the answer as soon as the system lets me.